# AngularJS end to end testing and hitting outside APIs vs Mocking

Tags: angularjs, testing, end-to-end

I have an php API feeding an AngularJS application.

I've been looking around for best practices regarding end to end testing and back ends.

Should I be mocking out my back end application when testing my angular app, or letting it hit the database and create/update/delete records?

I see merit for both arguments.

---

**The Good for Mocking**

If I mock out the API, the tests will be faster, more reliable, and start from a controllable, consistent state.

Fewer things can go wrong - there are simply fewer moving parts.

Since an API is a contract, I *should* be confident in the responses I'm getting, and comfortable mocking them out since they are a known factor.

---

**The Bad for Mocking**

Every time the API is updated, I'll have to update my mocks.

Mocking can add a lot of convoluted and hard to maintain code (though this isn't a foregone conclusion)

---

**The Good for Hitting the API**

The tests will exercise the full breadth and depth of the application, front JS client side through server side.

---

**The Bad for Hitting the API**

Slower tests
More setup (need to test locally, so I'll have to run and clean out the DB)
Inconsistent starting points (testing things like what the page looks like with no items will be impossible unless I'm constantly clearing out the DB)

---

I'm a bit torn on which way to go.

Unit tests will obviously mock out any dependencies, but end to end is a different story.

Thoughts?